# What is the difference between using single quotes and double quotes to query a Hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
{"user"=>
   {"bio"=>"rubyist",
   "created_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00", 
   "email"=>"paul@pauldix.net", 
   "id"=>61, "name"=>"paul", 
   "updated_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00"}}
```

What is the difference between using double double quotes and single quotes?:

```
attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)["user"]
attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)['user']
```

It seems that the first case works, but the second case does not find any key. I don't understand why.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference whatsoever... What's the exact error you get on the second one?

Comment: And if you exchange both rows in order, is it still the variant with the double quotes which works?

Comment: I don't believe that you are really getting the results you say you are. It is not possible in this case for Ruby to behave any differently.

Comment: @dmarkow: I tried to run this again today, and it worked...I guess it depends on the phase of the moon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange, they should work the same way and do for me:

```
>> user = {"user"=>
..        {"bio"=>"rubyist",
..          "created_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00", 
..          "email"=>"paul@pauldix.net", 
..          "id"=>61, "name"=>"paul", 
..          "updated_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00"}}.to_json 
#=> "{"user":{"bio":"rubyist","created_at":"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00","email":"paul@pauldix.net","id":61,"name":"paul","updated_at":"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00"}}"
>> attributes = JSON.parse(user)["user"] 
#=> {"bio"=>"rubyist", "created_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00", "email"=>"paul@pauldix.net", "id"=>61, "name"=>"paul", "updated_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00"}
>> attributes = JSON.parse(user)['user'] 
#=> {"bio"=>"rubyist", "created_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00", "email"=>"paul@pauldix.net", "id"=>61, "name"=>"paul", "updated_at"=>"2011-05-03T15:21:46+02:00"
```

Answer (score 7):

For the differences, there are already other good answers. I suspect that you do not have the one-byte single quote.

Maybe, you might have backquotes:

```
attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)[`user`]
```

or multibyte single quotes:

```
attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)[’user’]
```

If that's the case, they should be replaced by the one-byte single quotes.

Comment: And a +1 for all of us who have spent an hour staring at a screen, trying to figure out why some language is barfing, only to find out the problem was a curly double or single-quote that was hidden because the font we were using didn't HAVE curly quotes.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of a plain-text key like "user" it shouldn't really make any difference, it's strange it's not working indeed.
But if your key is an expression like, say, "#{variable_here}", it won't be evaluated unless you're using double quotes. Is this the case?

Answer (score 6):

One major difference between single quotes and double quotes in Ruby is that double quotes perform string interpolation, while single quotes don't:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > puts "one plus one is #{1 + 1}"
one plus one is 2
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > puts 'one plus one is #{1 + 1}'
one plus one is #{1 + 1}
 => nil
```

In your case, when accessing a hash, it should make no difference:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > {'one' => 1}['one']
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > {'one' => 1}["one"]
 => 1
```